# ggsave printing figures with transparent fill for geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to print a figure that is showing up as I want it to in R and R Studio with solid bars. However, when I save the figure using ggsave, the filled bars are now transparent. I tested the export function and that is working well so I think it must be ggsave.

```
epi %>%
  select(YearF, Quadrat, Area, MacroRA, MacroPercent) %>%
  filter(YearF == 2023) %>%
  drop_na(MacroPercent) %>%
  mutate(Quadrat = factor(Quadrat, levels = quadorder)) %>%
  mutate(MacroRA = factor(MacroRA, levels = Macroorder)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Quadrat, y=MacroPercent, fill=MacroRA)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Area, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete("Quadrat") + 
  scale_y_continuous("Relative Abundance", labels = scales::percent, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = WSPpal_macro) +
  theme_all +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5),
        panel.border = element_rect(size = 1),
        strip.background = element_rect(size = 1),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.text = element_text(size=5),
        legend.title = element_blank())

ggsave("Figs\\Relative Abundance.png", plot = p, width = 7, height = 3, units = "in")
```

[ggsave output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofWdy.png)

Is there a way to keep the fill from turning transparent?

Comment: Do you store the plot as `p`? You could also use `plot = last_plot()`. Does it change if you store to another device, i.e., `pdf` instead of `png`?

Comment: What is `WSPpal_macro`? Perhaps this contains semi-transparent colors? We can only guess, since you haven't included the data or palette you used to make the plot.